# How can i adapt the form to screen?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm working with AngularJS and Angular Material.
I'm making a login form but I have a issue, when I see the login form, it's very small on smartphone.

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hsHo.png)

How can i adapt the form to screen or make it more big on screen?

Notebook:

[notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtU3F.png)

Code:

```html
<body layout="row" style="background:#0277bd;" ng-cloak>

    <div flex>

    </div>

    <div flex flex-sm="80" flex-md="65" flex-gt-md="80" flex-gt-lg="33" layout="column" layout-align="center">
      <div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center">
          <img src="images/boxapp2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        </div>
        <md-card layout-padding>
          <form layout="column">

            <md-input-container flex>
              <label>Usuario</label>
              <input ng-model="login.username" name="userName" required>
            </md-input-container>

            <md-input-container flex>
              <label>Contraseña</label>
              <input ng-model="login.contrasena" type="password" required>
            </md-input-container>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Ingresar</md-button>
            </form>

            <span><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Accediendo desde: <?php echo $ip; ?></span>


        </md-card>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div flex>

    </div>




    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("loginboxapp",['ngMaterial','ngRoute'])
    .config(function($mdThemingProvider,$routeProvider){
      $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
          .primaryPalette('blue')
          .accentPalette('light-blue');
      })
    .controller("loginCTRL",function($scope){

    })
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a viewport meta tag into the head section of your template.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

**OR**

You can style these manually using media queries / breakpoints: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score -1):

You already set the width of the form to 80% centered, and that's what you got.

Your body has a row-layout and three divs inside. In the second div you set flex-sm="80" this means this div will occupy 80% of the screen width on small devices and the first and third div will get 10% each.

You can easily change this and use the full screen width. If for instance you want 100% on small devices, 80% on medium devices and 65% else then set your div like this

```html
<div flex-sm="100" flex-md="80" flex-gt-md="65" >
  
 </div>
```

see more here [Angular material grid system](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/grid)